# The public link of dropbox doestn't work

Tags: dropbox

Recently, I find the public link of dropbox such as https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/209352/Temp/Mycss.PNG don't work

I have to use share dropbox link such as https://www.dropbox.com/s/nr4bb00sd80pgl9/Mycss.PNG

It seems that share dropbox link works well.

1. Could tell me what is different between public link  and share dropbox link?
2. Can I always use  share dropbox link instead of public link ?

Comment: Both links work fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both links work OK. It seems like it took some time to the Public folder to refresh and it could not be ready by the time you checked.

You should use Public folder to public content to all the people and use "sharing options" when you have to share content to somebody in specific but not to everyone.

Regards

Comment: Thanks! but in my mind, everyone can access "share dropbox link", right?

Comment: If you choose "share" option and you do not specify any people, it will be available to everybody. So, for that case, it is right